# Electron get URL from Browser tab opened from App

Tags: angular, electron

I want to fetch the URL from a browser tab (Chrome, Brave, etc.) that was opened from an electron application.

Using Electron + Angular

I am implementing a connection to Discord in my desktop application, the user clicks on button in desktop application and a new browser( Chrome, Brave, etc.) is opened. Then the user authenticates in the browser after which a redirect URL is returned in the browser. I want to read that redirect URL in the browser and use it in the desktop application, because it contains the code I am suppose to use.

Angular Code used to open the window (In Angular component):

```
const win = window.open(endPoint, 'loginNav', strWindowFeatures );
```

I have configured my electron application to open these links in the browser (not electron window) by doing the following in main.js:

```
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  let currentURL = win.webContents.getURL();   
  shell.openExternal(url);
  return { action: 'deny' };
});
```

How do I read the the URL from the browser?

I have tried opening the Discord Auth window inside the electron application using a BrowserWindow object, but this won't work in production due to the fact that Discord Auth works with Http redirects and when the Electron application is installed in your machine it does not work with Http paths. The paths are something like *file:///dashboard*

Comment: you can only break the browser sandbox if you launch it in a certain way and have the handle to inject.  Using shell.open won't work.  Why not launch inside your Electron application?  (I've never used Electron, but I thought it was essentially a browser itself...)

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work when opening a new window inside a new Electron BrowserWindow, because Discord Auth works with http redirect's and an electron application installed in your computer does not work with http URL paths. Only in development does it work with http URL paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach is the right.
If what you are trying to do is to authenticate to Discord and redirect back to your electron app, the right approach is to use [Deep Links](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) to set up the default handler for your electron app. (Ex: `electron-fiddle://`).
And you need to set the `redirect_uri` to that uri so that a prompt will show up in the browser that will allow the user to the link in the app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are stating that my approach is wrong but Discord uses the same approach to establish their links. If you open your Discord application and connect to say Xbox then it opens the browser (Chrome, Brave, etc.).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve than, can you clarify ?

Comment: To summarize. Open browser(Chrome) window from electron-> then user is directed to discord Auth in the browser window. User Authenticates and is redirected (still in the browser window) to URL that is set up by me in Discord application -> with this redirect url a code is passed as query param which is used to authenticate the user. I want to extract that code in my electron app from the chrome window. I am looking into Deep Links. Thank you for the tip. But even using the code from the official documentation I am struggling to implement Deep Links. Do you know how to use them with Windows?

Comment: The deep links example in the official docs is pretty straight forward, if you just copy the first two code blocks in the docs it should work for you.  ['Deep Links | Electron - Examples'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app#examples).  
   If you are still having trouble, send a message I will try to create a working demo for you.